# If $E$ is the set of all infinite sequences of 0 and 1, $E$ equipotent to $E \times E$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

I am attempting to prove the following:

Let $E$ be the set of all infinite sequences of $0$ and $1$.  Prove that $E$ is equipotent to $E \times E$.

In order to do that, I am trying to show that a bijection exists between them.  We were given the hint: "Consider the map $(a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3},\cdots) \mapsto ((a_{1},a_{3},a_{5},\cdots), (a_{2}, a_{4}, a_{6},\cdots))$".

So far, I have been able to show that the map is injective; **what I am having difficulty with is showing that it is surjective**.

To do this, I suppose that $((a_{1_{j}}, a_{3_{j}}, a_{5_{j}}, \cdots), (a_{2_{j}}, a_{4_{j}}, a_{6_{j}}, \cdots))$ is any element in $E \times E$. Then, what I want is to show that this element must be in the image of $E$. I'm not sure how exactly to go about doing this, or making it mathematically precise.

I thank you ahead of time for your help.

Comment: You’re already done, to be quite frank. You can easily write down a preimage to the element you have written down. You already chose suggestive indexes.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm just not seeing it. Maybe it's because I'm extremely sleep deprived. If you could elaborate on what you mean by that, I would be ETERNALLY grateful.

Comment: Zip up $({a_1}_j, {a_3}_j, {a_5}_j, \ldots)$ and $({a_2}_j, {a_4}_j, {a_6}_j, \ldots)$ to get …?

Comment: Basically you have two sequences of $0$ and $1$: $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$, you then interweave them to create a new sequence, which is exactly the preimage of $(\mathbf a,\mathbf b)$.

Comment: How do I state that so it sounds mathematically rigorous?

Comment: “Let $(a,b) ∈ E × E$. Then $a = (a_1, a_2, a_3, …)$ for some $a_1, a_2, a_3, … ∈ \{0,1\}$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, b_3, …)$ for some $b_1, b_2, b_3, … ∈ \{0,1\}$. Let $x = (a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, a_3, b_3, …)$. Then the image of $x$ under the given map (let’s say it’s called $φ$) is $$φ(x) = φ((a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, a_3, b_3)) = ( (a_1, a_2, a_3, …), (b_1, b_2, b_3, …)) = (a,b).”$$